# Can a Force-sensitive person use the Force to communicate with other Force-sensitive people?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Apart from being a Force ghost, a power one can achieve only after a death, can one use the Force to "communicate" with the other Force-sensitive?

Imagine one scenario where Anakin and Obi-Wan were sent to a mission and they are separated on different parts of the planet or are even on different planets. All their means of communication (com-link and holographic messages) are broken. Can Anakin and Obi-Wan still communicate to each other using the Force?

It's not something like one shown in *Empire Strikes Back* where Luke sends a signal and Leia picks it up. It's kind of dedicated one to one communication. Is there any evidence in canon, that this power exists and is used?

Comment: Did you mean "force sensitives" (people who had latent force sensitivity but didn't necessarily have training to use it) or "force users" (trained people like Jedi or Sith). Your examples (Anakin, Obi-Wan, Plo Koon, Mace Windu) are all "Force users", not just "Force Sensitives".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Of two trained Jedi, if at least one was a member of a naturally-occurring telepathic species, then it may be possible for the two of them to be on opposite sides of a planet and be able to communicate, at least in a limited fashion using the Force.

If we assume two skilled Force users, then the power called [**Force Telepathy**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Telepathy) allows communication over vast distances depending on skill, power level, and innate telepathic ability. Even untrained users could experience telepathic connection if they were related, for instance. Luke and Leia were able to connect briefly even when Luke was just a padawan trainer.

**The more complicated answer:**

The terms "Force sensitive" and "Force user" are not synonymous. A sentient can be "Force sensitive" and not be a "Force user". All trained Jedi are Force users. An untrained padawan is most likely "Force sensitive" and that is why they were selected for training.

The term "Force sensitive" was used to describe sentients who were untrained in the ways of the Force. They were able to use it naturally to alter their probabilities of success, having a knack for certain skills such as flying or podracing, feats of speed or strength, or even to unconsciously manipulate the Force directly, with very sporadic results. This use of the Force by a Force sensitive person was considered unreliable (but detectable, if you knew where to look). *It is safe then to assume, that the untrained "Force sensitive" will not likely be able to use Force Telepathy to communicate reliably with anyone other than a highly trained Jedi.*

**So if I refine the question:** Can two trained Jedi who are on opposite sides of a planet still communicate via the Force even if their radios or other communications are offline?

Possibly, since one of the powers able to be granted or augmented by the Force is telepathy. But the telepathic ability granted by users of the Force if their species is NOT naturally telepathic is very limited. Only two people who shared a strong bond, such as family members, master and apprentice, or lovers would be able to utilize such a telepathic link and depending on the relationship, there may be limitations on what information could be shared, how long a message could be or how much detail could be shared. Most likely such a link would have a relatively limited range ([Wookieepedia's article on Force Telepathy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Telepathy) indicates a distance of a thousand miles or so.)

However, a Force user whose species was already telepathic could experience a boost of a thousand times greater range, effectiveness and clarity to their already existing natural telepathy. This would allow distances capable of encompassing an entire planet and in the case of powerful telepaths, potentially star-systems.

Comment: In that case: If Anakin is on a Mission with Master Plo Koon or with Mace Windu he can't use force telepathy to connect with them, but if he's with Obi-Van chances are high is it?

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong. Emperor communicated to Mara Jade in extremely clear way; between far away star systems; with neither of them being a telepath in any way (both regular humans species wise).

Comment: "Force Telepathy" made it possible. They were both FORCE USERS not FORCE SENSITIVES as the question asks. REVISE the Question to FORCE USERS and then the question is different.

Comment: @Thaddeus - The answer is STILL wrong, since there's an example of two non-telepathic beings communicating at interstellar distances; and there's zero canon support I am aware of indicating that it was limited to master/apprentice or lovers (neither of which Jade was to the Emperor)

Answer (score 1):

Two Force Users did NOT necessarily have to be within several kilometers to use telepathy.

- Case in point: Mara Jade, the Emperor's Hand.

  She could hear Palpatine's voice apparently anywhere in the galaxy via a telepathic link. (source: *Heir to the Empire*). Including hearing the Emperor's last dying order to kill Luke Skywalker.
- Another case in point: Plo Koon

  In Stark Hyperspace War comics, Plo Koon was able to communicate with his cousin Sha Koon, when he was on planet Troiken in Outer Rim and she was in Jedi Temple on Coruscant. But on top of his own (as per Qui-Gon) exceptional telepathic ability, he was helped both by kinship with her, AND by being Force-supported by a couple other Jedi.

  [image]

Comment: The question did not ask regarding two highly-capable "Force users" it asked about two "force sensitives" - people who were untrained in the use of the force and were NOT telepaths to start with. I imagine the Emperor as one of the most powerful force users of his era would be able to communicate with any Force user he decided he wanted to reach or at least any Dark Force aligned user.

Comment: @Thaddeus - The question explicitly mentioned Anakin (the strongest Jedi of his generation) and Obi-Wan (one of the most trained Masters) as the **only** example. Based on that I am pretty sure his use of "force sensitives" was more of a lack of awareness of fine distinction in terms than a desire to limit to untrained people. Oh, and I just checked his comment to your answer - again, his example is Plo Koon and Mace Windu